# Make a .contextMenu update with changes from PasteBoard

Tags: swiftui

I have a contextMenu view modifier for a view like this one:

```
Text("Some Text")
.contextMenu {
    Button(action: {
        editCodes(withTappedCode: codeOnDisplay, delete: true)
    }, label: {
         Text("Paste")
         Image(systemName: "doc.on.clipboard")
    })
    .disabled(!UIPasteboard.general.contains(pasteboardTypes: [aPAsteBoardType]))
}
```

The button should only be enabled when a certain Pasteboard Type is available. However this doesn't happen.

The disabled state is set when the context menu for the Button is first shown. After this any changes to the pasteboard will not modify the disabled state, even if the menu is closed and opened again.

This seems to only to happen if the modified view is refreshed in any way.

How can I change the disabled state, for the context menu button, with the Pasteboard type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to `UIPasteboard.changedNotification` to detect changes and refresh the view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var pasteDisabled = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Some Text")
            .contextMenu {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Paste")
                    Image(systemName: "doc.on.clipboard")
                }
                .disabled(pasteDisabled)
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIPasteboard.changedNotification)) { _ in
                pasteDisabled = !UIPasteboard.general.contains(pasteboardTypes: [aPAsteBoardType])
            }
    }
}
```

(You may also want to use `UIPasteboard.removedNotification`).

Comment: It works, but doesn't receive the notification when the Pasteboard change is from another app. This could happen when is in the background or in a iPadOS Split View...

Comment: @JoãoColaço It wasn't specified in the requirements (neither iPadOS nor background). But I added an answer under your new question.