# Receive notifications for focus changes between apps on Split View when using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, ipados

What should I observe to receive notifications in a View of focus changes on an app, or scene, displayed in an iPaOS Split View?

I'm trying to update some data, for the View, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64562488/1356575), when the user gives focus back to the app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that updates `pasteDisabled` whenever a `UIPasteboard.changedNotification` is received or a `scenePhase` is changed:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @State private var pasteDisabled = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Some Text")
            .contextMenu {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Paste")
                    Image(systemName: "doc.on.clipboard")
                }
                .disabled(pasteDisabled)
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIPasteboard.changedNotification)) { _ in
                updatePasteDisabled()
            }
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) { _ in
                updatePasteDisabled()
            }
    }

    func updatePasteDisabled() {
        pasteDisabled = !UIPasteboard.general.contains(pasteboardTypes: [aPAsteBoardType])
    }
}
```

Comment: The scenePhase seems to change when the app goes to the background, but doesn't change when the focus changes between apps when they are in a Split View. Without this I cannot know if the app has lot focus.